# In performance test if we need to go back to Home page to access next link then can i do this by adding urls in CSV file?

Tags: jmeter

If there are 5 links on the home page (a,b, c,d, e, f) and 3 links (g,h,i) are accessible via Next arrow on Home page.
In script if first click on link "a" from Home page then I can see refer as Home page url in script . While doing this by CSV data file I cant see refer so Is it the right approach to perform load test in scenarios like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add Referer header manually by adding JMeter Config Element [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager). Add HTTP Header Manager as a child to which you want to manage headers (for example, HTTP samplers that request "a" link.)

If Referer header is always Home Page Url, then you can hard-code that value in HTTP Header Manager.

[image]

If not, then you can use the CSV file which contains Links, add one more column for Referer URLs in the same CSV file.

[image]

**Note:** Whether adding Referer header is compulsory or not, depends on the criticality of the header. If the server needs **it** to process your request, then definitely you should add it otherwise, you can ignore.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . please clear on following doubt I have run the test with all urls in CSV file and getting 200 response code . But in this way I am accesing urls directly not via home page as user does while accessing website . So will this make difference?

Comment: As long as you are simulating the requests properly and getting successful response codes for all requests (verify HTML response along with response code using View Results Tree). The Eventual goal is to put the load on the server as per Load Distribution Goals. We simulate the load as close as possible to browser behavior. use Network tab (F12 in any browser) to compare the requests sent by JMeter and browser.

Comment: What you should keep in mind is that you simulate the load as close as possible to real-world traffic, like a number of total users, a number of concurrent users, types of users, most used transactions, geographical distribution of users, cache usage by browser etc.

Comment: There are many things to consider. JMeter allows you to simulate web traffic by either recording (easiest way) or by manually adding samplers to the Test Plan. What JMeter does is send those recorded or added samplers, in the order, they are added.You have to take care of Cookies (using HTTP Cookie Manager) to make the user/thread is alive and there are many other things to take care like parameterization for providing different inputs (like usernames), correlation of dynamic values (like Session IDs).

Comment: thats really helpful reply. still have one ambiguity that why we apply think time to simulate user behavior in load test scripts .

Comment: because to navigate in the web pages or filling the forms definitely takes time by end users. They can't send/visit pages as soon as response arrives from the server. Let's take Login page, this request will only be sent after entering username/password by the end user which will take at least 10-15 seconds, which is called User Think Time.

Comment: In JMeter, if you don't keep User Think Time (using Timer component), will send the requests as soon as it receives the response from the server and will end up putting more load on the server than the expected.

Comment: ok, so in this case if I do recording I need to go back to Home page to access second link  and then again need to visit Home page to access third link . To simulate this action I added all the urls associates with hypoerlinks

Comment: hyperlinks in csv file and accessed directly without navigating back to Home page . While recording I am getting Home page request after accessing each hyperlink .Also, in real scenario I need to access around 50 such hyperlinks .Recording is creating a lengthy script and so think of this method  and wanted to get this confirmed if this approach is correct ?Thanks for your time Naveen

Comment: The Recording is not compulsory though it is the easiest way. It is like Starting Point. You can always customize as per your needs.  reading hyperlinks from csv is as follows: "Visit Home Page -> Visit all links". In the recording, the flow is  "Visit Home page -> visit first link -> visit home page again -> visit second link". Both are correct. It depends on how you want to define a TRANSACTION.

Comment: Thanks Naveen . If tehre is pagination also then also both the ways are correct for performance testing . Please clear this point as well

Comment: You define business transactions like Login , ViewFeed, postFeed, sendMessage, LikeFeed, CommentFeed, Comment Feed etc for facebook app. Similarly, you define your business transactions which you want to perform during the load test. You can contact stake holders  (dev, analyst etc) to determine the critical transactions.  So, as I mentioned both FLOWs are correct and it is up to you and the team to decide which one to follow and you take that decision to match with real-time usage (as close as possible) by end users. I would suggest you study the basics of performance testing. Google It :).